# Modeling an Amazon like metastore with Products from many Merchants in mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, nosql

I'm new to MongoDB so I just wanted to get some outside critique of my schema.  I'm trying to build what is a akin to a metastore. I'm going to be selling products for a number of different merchants and some of the merchants are likely to have the same products.  I should also add that i'm building this in Rails using Mongoid.

This is what my Product document looks like currently.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4f4c8ad406164f46f1000085"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2012-02-28T08:05:40Z"),
    "manufacturer_id" : ObjectId("4f4c88bd06164f46f1000068"),
    "manufacturer_name" : "Minka Lavery",
    "manufacturer_sku" : null,
    "merchant_products" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("4f4c8ad406164f46f1000086"),
            "_type" : "CommissionJunctionProduct",
            "merchant_name" : "1800lighting.com",
            "merchant_id" : ObjectId("4f4c8ad406165f46f1000086"),
            "sku" : "8875981",
            "buy_url" : "http://www.foobar.com",
            "price" : 10.80,
            "in_stock" : true,
            "updated_at" : ISODate("2012-02-28T08:05:40Z"),
            "created_at" : ISODate("2012-02-28T08:05:40Z")
        }
    ],
    "name" : "Minka Lavery 8717-44 Bridgeport 1 Light Outdoor",
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2012-02-28T08:05:40Z")
}
```

It has many merchant products with in it.  Each datasource of products has it's own _type.

I also have references to other documents such as Merchants and Manufacturer.  These are just used as a central place where I can update their display names.  In the case of Manufacturers, many merchants might name them slightly different so I keep an array of aliases so I know what display name to use in the product.  I have a similar setup for Merchants, although they don't have aliases I still want to be able to customize their name and have it propagate through out the products.

When I eventually display the products to the user I loop through all the merchant products and figure out which one is the best one to show the user.  I was thinking of having a background script that just moves the best merchant_product to the first spot of the array.

The one thing I've noticed from this setup is creating merchant_products and updating them seems kind of difficult.  It doesn't happen often but the logic is complex to make sure I don't create duplicate products and I'm able to update prices.  Also I can't really show all the merchant products a merchant has.

I could go into more about what I've done but I think I might learn more from seeing how other people would mockup something like this up.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Schema.org. The models defined there are document-oriented, and I find relating them to MongoDB very easy.
Here is how a Product is modeled.

http://www.schema.org/Product

What you will notice is that Product has Offers, that can be from different Merchants.
You can store Offers in a different collection, and then manage them separately. That wil also help you sort offers on different criteria such as (location, price or merchant rating) directly through the queries.

You don't have to store a Dbref of Offer in the Product collection. Just store the product id within each offer document.

Comment: Shouldn't I be storing something about the offer in the product? When I display the products I'm going to have to do a lot of queries for the offer info otherwise.

Comment: You'll need two queries to display the product page; first one to get the product details from the 'Products' collection, another one to get the offers from the 'Offers' collection. Both the queries can take the same 'product id' as the input criteria.

Comment: Isn't that kind of inefficient?  If I want to show 10 products on a page I'm going to have to make 11 queries right? 1 to get all the products and then 10 to get the offers for each product.  I feel like that is kind of going against what I've read your supposed to do in mongodb.

Comment: If you want to show 10 Products, then also you will need two queries, only your criteria will change.

Comment: may I suggest having the products in MongodDB as a datastore but use something as Solr or ElasticSearch for querying. There's some nice connectors between the two I believe for automatic updating, etc. sorting/filtering capabilities of either Solr or ES far exceed the capabilities of MongoDB

Comment: I agree, that is what I would propose for a real world application. However, last I checked, there weren't any nice connectors. So, pushes to index have to be programmed. There will always be a chance to have stale information about the offer in the Solr/ES index. So to be accurate, price for each offer has to be fetched from DB. This can be an AJAX query from the Ui to have better percieved performance.